# Nonlinear derivative free optimization in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to solve a non-linear optimization problem with equality constraints.

I want argument to be a vector and want derivative free method.

It seems that `NLsolve.jl` supports such problem using an algorithm of `:LD_SLSQP` but I cannot write the correct code

Maybe, the problem is `grad`, which should be "empty" according to the [`README`](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl)

Could anyone tell me the right way to write code?

```
using NLopt

function f(x,grad)
    x1 = x[1]
    x2 = x[2]
    out= log(x1)+0.9*log(x2)
    return out
end

function const1(x,grad)
    out = Array{Float64}(2)
    out[1] = x[1]+x[2]-10.0
    out[2] = 0.0
    return out
end

opt = Opt(:LD_SLSQP, 2)

lower_bounds!(opt, [1e-8, 1e-8])
upper_bounds!(opt, [10.0, 10.0])

max_objective!(opt,f)

maxtime!(opt, 20)

equality_constraint!(opt,const1,[1e-8,1e-8])
```

Comment: The `LD_SLSQP` method is not the gradient free method. You probably meant `LN_PRAXIS`. Not sure how it handles equality constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dan Gets, `LD_SLSQP` is not derivative free.

changing algorithm to `LN_COBYLA` solves the issue!